# Can't see the ListView divider

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

I added a divider to my listview but there is nothing there. The ListView stays comepletely the same as if there wasn't any divider set.

This is ListView XML:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_language"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@drawable/shadow" />
```

@drawavble/shadow XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item 
    >
    <shape 
        >
        <gradient android:startColor="@color/shadow_start"
            android:endColor="@color/shadow_end"
            android:angle="90"/>
        <stroke 
            android:height="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

Why won't the divider appear on ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should also add the `android:dividerHeight` property to your layout

Comment: Thanks! The divider is now shown. But another problem appeared, if you happen to know the solution. The divider is now on TOP of every listview element. Is there a way to move it on the bottom? Thanks again! EDIT: Nevermind, the divider is shown between elements, not on top, the last element doesn't have a divider :)

Comment: do you want a divider also for the last item? It does not make sense to me

Comment: Yes, that's what I was aiming for. I want the last item also to have a divider. I think I'll solve it by adding another divider drawable under the listview though.

Comment: ok, still it does not make sense to me.. You can also try to add a fake element to your dataset and in the getView if the element of the data set is the last you change its visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `selector` root element with `layer-list` in your shadow xml file.